# How to set foreground Image to ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I am new in Android App development. I want to set Foreground image to Image button in API level 19. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Foreground drawable cannot help you with this. Use another `ImageView` instead, place it on the same `FrameLayout` of the background img

Comment: @TamHuynh Thanks for editing.can you share sample code for this ?

Comment: @TamHuynh I tested with ( questionOption1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check) ),image in background but I want to show in foreground

Comment: Refer this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm

Comment: Post your relevant code and what you've tried to achieve what you want but fail in the question, or you will get lots of downvotes.

Comment: You can use  FrameLayout.I hope that it can be solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample code, use this for a layout of 1 answer:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/answer_section"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/house_img"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/answer_check"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/check_img"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

You use 2 different `ImageView` for 2 images so they can work separately, like doing animation, show/hide with conditions...

Comment: Thanks a lot.I tested and It works perfectly.You saved my day